# How to create an auto increment column and have it auto filled

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
private void AddAutoIncrementColumn(DataTable dt)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
    column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;


    dt.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

I have an existing DataTable and want to create an auto-incremented column. That is, when i create the column i want it to automatically fill in the value 0......x. I am using the code above. But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set autonumber for DataTable after it already has data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179724/set-autonumber-for-datatable-after-it-already-has-data)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4310948/2185245
This post has an answer you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
private void AddAutoIncrementColumn()
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
    column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

    // Add the column to a new DataTable.
    DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
    table.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179724/set-autonumber-for-datatable-after-it-already-has-data

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have an EXISTING data table to which I want to add an auto-incremented column.

Comment: Please Check link that i gave in comments . Hope this will help you Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on `Datatable` called `CreateDataReader`. So, clone your original `datatable`, add the identity column, create a `datareader` from the original table, then load the cloned table with the data reader. This will generate numbers in the identity column in the cloned table, then discard the original table and use the clone, eg

```
// original data table
DataTable origDT;

// create a reader
DataReader dr = origDT.CreatDataReader();

//clone original
DataTable clonedDT = origDT.Clone();

//add identity column
clonedDT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(){AutoIncrement=true});

//load clone from reader, identity col will auto-populate with values
clonedDT.Load(dr);
```